# Android Studio Emulator Quick boot State saving process and load state process is very slow

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am using android emulator provided by the android studio and since android studio version 3.1 google has provided quick boot mode to start AVD in just a 2-3 seconds.

For booting device faster they are saving screenshot and when we boot device again then they simply load screenshot which is a way faster then older ways in AVD but in my case saving screenshot takes too much time to save the state and also when i  boot it again, it takes approx. 30+ seconds to load the state which is saved. So, i have two questions:

1. Why the saving state and load state process is too slow in my laptop? My laptop has 8GB RAM and i3 5th gen processor which is i think enough to save and load state faster.
2. As a trick to solve above problem i have saved screenshot once and then selected **NO** in save quick-boot state. So, i think emulator should have to use the saved state which i have saved manually once but here emulator results are variable. Sometime it uses saved state which i have saved and sometime it boot normally (Not quick booting). So, i want to know that am i thinking in right way to fix my problem or not? (**NOTE** - I am using android studio `3.2 Canary` version which have a snapshot option, using which i am saving current state and turning off saving quick-boot state option).

Answer (score 2):

Answering your first question: Your laptop must be having a Hard disk(HDD). This saving state is super fast and fun to use if your laptop has a solid state drive(SSD). The saving and loading is slow because hard-disks are slow(in comparison to SSD of course!) and you have to save so much of data in your snapshot.

Just think of this as copying some data to a pen drive from your laptop. It takes a fixed amount of time based on the read/write speed of the pen-drive. It has nothing to do with the processor you use or the amount of ram your machine has. So, even if you update your laptop with an i7 and 16gb of ram, you won't find any change! I personally have switched off this feature and prefer a cold boot.

For your second question, I am not very sure. It can be a canary version bug. Though I do like your idea of saving just one snapshot and re-using it.

Comment: +1 for your explanation. I accept that i am using HDD so, it's data read-write speed is slower then SDD but i think quick boot should take lesser time then cold boot. In my case both of boot mode takes same time.

Comment: Yeah.. In my case also both take somewhat the same time. I guess we HDD guys have to live with it!